# Moving a directory without clobbering an existing one

Tags: linux, unix, directory, filesystems, posix

The [documentation for the `rename()` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/rename.html) in the *Single UNIX Specification* describes that `rename(old, new)` will overwrite an existing directory `new`, if it is empty and `old` is also a directory.

I'm trying to find a way to rename a directory while making sure that an existing directory with the new name will never be overwritten (which could happen if two concurrent processes try to rename a directory to the same new name).

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is not actually possible within the POSIX API, unless there is some way of `locking` a directory. I'd also accept an answer with a plausible explanation stating that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `link` which is atomic and fails if destination exists. So something like :

```
if (link("orig", "dest")) unlink("orig");
```

should work. `link` will atomically succeed if `dest` doesn't exits, so to complete your `rename` it is sufficient to unlink `orig`. If `dest` exists, `link will fail.

Comment: For files, that's an idea I haven't thought about yet! But sadly my use case involves the original and destination files being directories.

Comment: If you have appropriate privileges you can link dirs (as POSIX.1 says). It tried it in the past, and it worked, of course you should be careful not to make a circular path on the filesystem..

Comment: AFAIK OS X is the only widely-used POSIX OS that allows multiple links to directories, not counting the `.` and `..` entries. Linux certainly doesn't.

Comment: It was widely supported in the past (with privileges) on most UNIXes. Now Linux filesystems prohibit it I think. But this is extremely useful, Apple's TimeMachine use it intensively...

Answer (score 0):

Check if directory exist

```
# before rename, check if file exist
if [ -d new ]
then
# here do what you like if dir exist. 
else
#dir does not exist so rename
    rename(old, new)
fi
```

Comment: Sadly, this only works if only one process is running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some form of synchronization mechanism - see some basic info on locks e.g. at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29).

The [link()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/link.html) function will atomically create a new link which can help you to create a lock file.  The atomicity will make sure that more concurrent processes won't be able to create the same lock file.